# Index error:list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, list, indexing, variable-assignment

I want to:

1. Take two `input`s as integers separated by a space (but in string form).
2. Club them using `A + B`.
3. Convert this `A + B` to integer using `int()`.
4. Store this integer value in `list` `C`.

*My code:*

```
C = list()
for a in range(0, 4):
    A, B = input().split()
    C[a] = int(A + B)
```

but it shows:

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

I am unable understand this problem. How is `a` is going out of the `range` (it must be starting from `0` ending at `3`)?

Why it is showing this error?

Comment: Please fix the code indentation in your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why your error is occurring:

> You can only reference an `index` of a `list` if it already exists. On the last line of every iteration you are referring to an index that is yet to be created, so for example on the first iteration you are trying to **change** the `index` `0`, which does not exist as the `list` is empty at that time. The same occurs for every iteration.

---

The correct way to add an item to a list is this:

```
C.append(int(A + B))
```

Or you could solve a hella lot of lines with an ultra-pythonic list comprehension. This is built on the fact you added to the `list` in a loop, but this simplifies it as you do not need to assign things explicitly:

```
C = [sum(int(item) for item in input("Enter two space-separated numbers: ").split()) for i in range(4)]
```

The above would go in place of all of the code that you posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to append the element to your list like this:

```
C.append(int(A+B))
```

And don't worry about the indices

Answer (score 0):

Here's a far more pythonic way of writing your code:

```
c = []
for _ in range(4): # defaults to starting at 0
    c.append(sum(int(i) for i in input("Enter two space-separated numbers").split()))
```

Or a nice little one-liner:

```
c = [sum(int(i) for i in input("Enter two space-separated numbers").split()) for _ in range(4)]
```

Comment: I won't down-vote as I made the same mistake at first, but I will give you a chance to correct the fact that you can't get the sum of two strings in your list comprehension. It raises a `TypeError`.